# How do i get kivymd useranimationcard to my app

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i am working on a project and am trying to add an animation card to it. i cot an example from the kivymd documentation but still i cant get it to run. when i run the example i get an error. i usually use the examples to implement on my program. i need help getting the example to run.

this is the code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.useranimationcard import MDUserAnimationCard
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch
from kivy.uix.image import Image

# Your content for a contact card.
Builder.load_string(
    """
#:import get_hex_from_color kivy.utils.get_hex_from_color


<TestAnimationCard@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: dp(10)
    spacing: dp(10)
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Widget:
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Free call"
        Widget:
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Free message"
        Widget:

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Video call"
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "camera-front-variant"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Call Viber Out"
        secondary_text: "[color=%s]Advantageous rates for calls[/color]" % get_hex_from_color(app.theme_cls.primary_color)
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "phone"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Call over mobile network"
        secondary_text: "[color=%s]Operator's tariffs apply[/color]" % get_hex_from_color(app.theme_cls.primary_color)
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "remote"
"""
)


class IconLeftSampleWidget(ILeftBodyTouch, MDIconButton):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    user_animation_card = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "KivyMD Examples - User Animation Card"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        def main_back_callback():
            toast("Close card")

        if not self.user_animation_card:
            self.user_animation_card = MDUserAnimationCard(
                user_name="User Name",
                path_to_avatar="path_to_avatar",
                callback=main_back_callback,
            )
            self.user_animation_card.box_content.add_widget(Factory.TestAnimationCard())
        self.user_animation_card.open()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/Allano/Desktop/exe/New folder (2)/MDtest.py", line 83, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 323, in do_layout
     c.size = (w, h)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1371, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Allano\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivymd\utils\fitimage.py", line 63, in adjust_size
     (img_x, img_y) = self.image.texture.size
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't specified the image path.
Change this particular line of your code by specifying the image path.

```
path_to_avatar="image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to "get user Animation Card work to your App", you might need flexibility on how to use the User Animation Card apart from the example.

You can customize you app to use User Animation Card from a `.kv file` like the example below.

In this example we're going to use `left_action_items` of `MDtoolbar` to show User Animation Card when clicked.

Do not forget to add a path to avatar (image).

python code (test.py).

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch
from kivymd.uix.useranimationcard import MDUserAnimationCard


class IconLeftSampleWidget(ILeftBodyTouch, MDIconButton):
    pass


class ShowUserAnimationCard(MDBoxLayout):
    user_animation_card = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(ShowUserAnimationCard, self).__init__(**kw)

    def builder(self):
        if not self.user_animation_card:
            self.user_animation_card = MDUserAnimationCard(
                user_name=" user_name",
                path_to_avatar="path/to/avatar" # remember to add path to your avatar (image)
            )
            self.user_animation_card.box_content.add_widget(Factory.TestAnimationCard())
        self.user_animation_card.open()


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kw)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

kivy file, (test.kv).

```
ShowUserAnimationCard:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        size_hint_y: dp(0.17)
        title: 'Test App'
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.builder()]]

    MDBoxLayout:
    # To push MDToolbar at the top

<TestAnimationCard@MDBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: dp(10)
    spacing: dp(10)
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Edit Account"
        text_size: "1dp"

        secondary_text: "[color=#009999]Edit Main Account[/color]"
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "account-edit"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Credit Card"
        secondary_text: "[color=#009999] Credit Card Outline[/color]"
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "credit-card-outline"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Delete account"
        secondary_text: "[color=#009999]Permanently delete this account[/color]"
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "face"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.useranimationcard import MDUserAnimationCard
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch
from kivy.uix.image import Image

# Your content for a contact card.
Builder.load_string(
    """
#:import get_hex_from_color kivy.utils.get_hex_from_color


<TestAnimationCard@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: dp(10)
    spacing: dp(10)
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Widget:
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Free call"
        Widget:
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Free message"
        Widget:

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Video call"
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "camera-front-variant"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Call Viber Out"
        secondary_text: "[color=%s]Advantageous rates for calls[/color]" % get_hex_from_color(app.theme_cls.primary_color)
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "phone"

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "Call over mobile network"
        secondary_text: "[color=%s]Operator's tariffs apply[/color]" % get_hex_from_color(app.theme_cls.primary_color)
        IconLeftSampleWidget:
            icon: "remote"
"""
)


class IconLeftSampleWidget(ILeftBodyTouch, MDIconButton):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    user_animation_card = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "KivyMD Examples - User Animation Card"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        def main_back_callback():
            toast("Close card")

        if not self.user_animation_card:
            self.user_animation_card = MDUserAnimationCard(
                user_name="User Name",
                path_to_avatar="pathoftheimageyouwanttoview\\00000.png",
                callback=main_back_callback,
            )
            self.user_animation_card.box_content.add_widget(Factory.TestAnimationCard())
        self.user_animation_card.open()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Friend the code is correct you just have to specify the path where the image to be exposed is.